# Getting a dynamically typed ServiceStack.redis client in C#

Tags: dynamic, redis, servicestack, typing

I am new to C# as a whole and was wondering how I would achieve the functionality described below.  Currently this is not compiling at the indicated lines.  What I would like the code to do is:

Iterate through each KVP,
Query the db using the keystring as the table name
Return a list

```
var dbCon = dbConnectionFactory.OpenDbConnection();
Dictionary<string, Type> ibetDic = getFromSomeWhere();
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Type> entry in ibetDic)
    {
        Type type = entry.Value;
        var typedRedisClient = redis.GetTypedClient<type>();/*not compiling here*/
        String sql = "USE ibet SELECT * FROM " + entry.Key;
        var itemList = dbCon.SqlList<type>(sql);/*not compiling here*/
        foreach (var tableRow in itemList )
        {
            //store with redistypedclient
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closest thing to an answer I have found however this means that I have to pass in the type rather than be able to access it through the dictionary as I was wanting above:

```
public void GetAndStoreIntKey<T>(string tableName) where T : IHasId<int>
    {
        var dbCon = dbConnectionFactory.OpenDbConnection();
        String sql = "USE ibet SELECT * FROM " + tableName;
        var items = dbCon.SqlList<T>(sql);
        var typedRedisClient = redis.As<T>();

        foreach (T item in items)
        {
            typedRedisClient.SetEntry(UrnId.CreateWithParts<T>(new string[] {item.Id + ""}), item);
        }
    }
```

Usage like :

```
 GetAndStoreIntKey<Sport>("Sport");
```